# Fix acorn squash that I baked too long, now too dry

Tags: squash

I baked some acorn squash too long, and now it is a bit too dry, not juicy.

If I mash the squash, what might I add to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

## Butter.

I'm sure some folks consider it a "crutch," or cheating. But butter fixes all sorts of cooking sins. The fat in butter will help bring the squash back to life. Some broth, olive oil, milk, cream, or other (flavorful) liquid will also help.

The most important thing is to make sure you're adding at least some fat to the mashed squash, and stir it in as you go. Fat will help emulsify the added liquid and the (dry) squash so that it becomes a single thing, rather than just being squash in a liquidy bath.